# Meteor.JS: How to Remove All Packages from a Project

Tags: meteor

I want to remove the meteor installation from my meteor project directory while keeping my source code intact, so that I can archive the project without the installed packages. I also want the package configuration to be retained in the archive so that I can re-install the project without having to re-add and re-remove the packages again.

How do I do this?

Comment: Delete `(project root)/.meteor/local/` and archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor already creates a `.gitignore` file for you. That file tells you everything that should be archived. So you can simple look at that file and only archive that (either by deleting everything else, or just writing a script that reads the `.gitignore` file and interprets it). Alternatively, of course, you could just add everything to git (in which case git will interpret the `.gitignore` file for you), and then create an archive from the git repo.

Of course, that `.gitignore` file only excludes `.meteor/local`, so as Kyll already said, you could just delete that folder.